# To "soften the impact" in German

Tags: translation, english-to-german

I'm trying to figure out how one formulates the expression "to soften the impact of". For example:

> If you save money, you can soften the impact of the holidays on your budget.

I've see the word "abfedern", but this seems to only apply to physical things, unless I'm mistaken?

Answer (score 4):

A quick [Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=soften+the+impact+deutsch) [reveals](https://www.linguee.de/englisch-deutsch/uebersetzung/soften+the+impact.html):

> Folgen abfedern
>   Folgen (ab)mildern
>   Folgen abschwächen
>   (negative) Einwirkung verringern

Any of those and the others at the "reveals" link can be used.

Comment: Thank you! So, I can use "abfedern" even in the figurative sense such as 

"...die Wirkung von Ferien auf unser Budget abfedern"?

Comment: "(negative) Folgen abfedern" or "Einwirkung verringern" would be my choice.

Comment: @Mark Yes, you can use it in figurative sense, too. Another possibility would be "die Auswirkungen der Ferien".

Answer (score 2):

To really make it *sound* German a more typical phrase would include instead of:

> Wenn Sie Geld sparen, können Sie die Auswirkungen der Feiertage auf Ihr Budget mildern.

something  a bit more whiny or dreadful:

> Wenn Sie Geld sparen, können Sie die **Belastung** Ihres Budgets durch den Urlaub mildern.
>
> Wenn Sie Geld sparen, können Sie die **finanziellen Konsequenzen** des Urlaubs für Ihr Budget mildern.

This 'sound' is of course full of cliché and stereotype, as these are almost required phrasings and almost idioms in German journalism.
Not following this trodden path is of course welcome and in such a case closely mirroring the source a more neutral translation for "impact" would be:

> Wenn Sie Geld gespart haben, können Sie den **Einfluss** eines Urlaubs auf Ihr Budget klein halten.

Answer (score 2):

Often we hear the railway term *puffern/[abpuffern](https://www.dwds.de/wb/abpuffern)* or the noun *[Polster](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Polster)* in this context:

> Wenn Sie zuvor Geld ansparen, können Sie die Urlaubskosten abpuffern.
>   Ein zuvor angespartes Polster kommt ihrem Urlaubsbudget zugute<sup>*</sup>.

*<sub>OT: [zugutekommen](https://www.dwds.de/wb/zugutekommen) is a separable verb</sub>

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to some other options, which may fit -in cases barely- to some extent:

> - entschärfen.
>     Wenn Sie Geld sparen, können Sie die Auswirkungen (Folgen) der Urlaubstage auf Ihr Budget entschärfen.
> - entkräftigen.
>     Wenn Sie Geld sparen, können Sie die Auswirkungen (Folgen) der Urlaubstage auf Ihr Budget entkräftigen.

Also possible options are:

> - verkleinern.
> - vermindern
> - klein halten
>     ...

Answer (score 1):

I don't really get the meaning of the English sentence. Does 'if you save money' mean

> 1 wenn Sie in einer Ansparphase sind = immer Geld zur Seite legen = nie alles Geld, das Sie haben, ausgeben, um ein Kapital zusammenzusparen
>
> 2 wenn Sie sparsam (ein sparsamer Mensch) sind = wenn Sie Ihr Geld zusammenhalten
>
> 3 wenn Sie (hier an diesem Punkt) nicht so viel Geld ausgeben wollen

?

And does 'budget' here mean:

> 5 alles dem '*you*' zur Verfügung stehende Geld
>
> 6 alles auf einen Zeitraum (Monat, Jahr) bezogen verfügbare Geld
>
> 7 das für einen bestimmten Zweck vorgesehene Geld = Kostenrahmen

?

All German sentences I read hear dont't make sense to me, but the English sentence may be more or less vague as well.

Comment: Es tut mir Leid für die Verwirrung. "Budget" wird häufig in amerikanischem English sehr locker benutz, und knüpft meistens an deinem fünften Vorschlag an. Mit "save money", meine ich, nicht so viel Geld im Vorfeld der Ferien ausgeben, so dass du alles leisten kannst. Ein Polster aufbauen.

Comment: Ich ahne jetzt halbwegs den Sinn. Vielleicht: _Wenn Sie im Vorfeld Geld für den Urlaub auf die Seite legen, dann lässt sich die finanzielle Belastung besser verkraften._ Oder: _Am besten sparen Sie vorher auf den Urlaub, dann rutschen Sie nicht ins Minus, wenn Sie die Hotelrechnung bezahlen müssen._ Oder: _Wenn Sie vorher Geld für den Urlaub auf die Seite gelegt haben, dann bleibt die finanzielle Belastung für ihr Konto (im Urlaubsmonat) im Rahmen._ Oder _Durch Sparen im Vorfeld lässt sich die finanzielle Belastung durch einen Urlaub in Grenzen halten._  [weiter ...]

Comment: [... weiter] Das Problem für mich war: Der Satz ist redundant, er bezeichnet im Grunde nichts weiter als den Sinn des Sparens, verkürzt ausgedrückt sagt er: Wenn Sie Geld sparen, dann haben Sie dieses Geld für Ausgaben zur Verfügung, oder: Durch Sparen können Sie bei begrenztem Budget auch größere Ausgaben finanzieren, ohne  einen Kredit aufnehmen zu müssen, z.B. einen Überziehungskredit. Hm. Für wen ist diese Information gedacht?